# Spring page redirection: Page not found issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to run a sample project from [This site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/). Jboss starts with out any error but when i enter the path

> `http://localhost:8080/Spring3Hibernate/index`

i get the exception "The requested resource is not available".

My spring-servlet.xml class is

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

        <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.101.163:3306/db_roseindia"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

and web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and controller class is

```
package main.java.net.viralpatel.contact.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import main.java.net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact;
import main.java.net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")

    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

        System.out.println("In Index method");

        map.put("contact", new Contact());
        map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

        return "contact";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
    Contact contact, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("in ADD method");

        contactService.addContact(contact);

        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{contactId}")
    public String deleteContact(@PathVariable("contactId")
    Integer contactId) {

        System.out.println("IN delete method");

        contactService.removeContact(contactId);

        return "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

and when i try to run the project i get the

```
10:33:25,415 WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring3Hibernate/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

In Lib folder, i have these jars

[image]

and in Build path i have 
[image]

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I would be so much thankful for your precious time and help.
I am using eclipes 3.4 and jboss 4.2

Comment: @Shahzeb : i made a new web based project and rename it to Spring3Hibernate ( remove mavem from project name) I am using Eclipse 3.4.0 with JBoss 4.2.0

Comment: @Shahzeb I have added my pom.xml so where should i make changes to run the project ;: "yes, i am shahzeb and i exists ;)"

Comment: @Shahzeb I am not using Maven, i have downloaded this project and simply copy its file into a new "dynamic web project". I changed artifictId to Spring3Hibernate (removed Maven) but still no luck..

Comment: @Shahzeb it didn't worked, i tryed ( with both "\" and "/") but no luck.

Comment: back again . Try changing `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to   `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`

Comment: @Shahzeb Still no luck with .xhtml, can it be a problem due to some jars in lib folder of in class path. coz when i randomly add/remove jars, some times i get new exceptions too.

Comment: hey buddy we have been on this for an hour now . When you had different exceptions you should have said so . First problem is that url is incorrect . If by doing any of the stuff I have said so far or somebody else at point if you get any other exception you need to tell us about it. Try producing that exception again and post that.

Comment: @Shahzeb Thank you so much for your precious time. Let me try a bit more and i will re post my issues again if i came with. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site from where you are taking the code, the servlet mapping in the web.xml is done like this.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

In your code which your have posted above its like

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

The Url Pattern means:

```
/ by itself is the default servlet called if there are no other matches.
```

and

```
/* mapping in web.xml it answers all requests except other path mappings.
```

Check and use what you really want.

Comment: I tried "/" first but no success, then i changed it to /* (a try) but again application did not run.

Comment: can you try with <url-pattern>/Spring3Hibernate/*</url-pattern>.

Comment: it didn't worked, Even not getting the Warning regarding page not found.

Answer (score 0):

is it `http://localhost:8080/Spring3Hibernate/index` or `http://localhost:8080/Spring3-Hibernate/index`

please verify your context path is correct

Comment: i right clicked on Project and select RunAs (run on server) and the path generated was (http://localhost:8080/Spring3Hibernate/) i added index, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
At Class Level specify RequestMapping as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController
```

Then at method level specify

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map)
```

Now try the URL as

> "http://localhost:8080/Spring3Hibernate/contact/list"